# iptables проброс портов. Перенаправление на другое устройство

Tags: linux, iptables

Я немного знаком с линуксом, но затруднения имеются с iptables.

Внешний IP - динамический

- Локальный адрес роутера - 192.168.1.1
- Адрес Raspberry Pi 3 Model B(OS Raspbian,на основе Debian) -
  192.168.1.20
- Адрес PC - 192.168.1.147

Открыл порт 3389 для Raspberry, мне нужно сделать включаемый/выключаемый проброс порта на PC.

Т.е форвардинг. Как сделать это правильно в моем случае?

Пояснение: 
В итоге должно получиться подключение -

> внешка->роутер->Raspberry(0/1)->PC.

При 0 - форвардинг отключен, т.е доступа к PC нет. При 1 - PC Доступен для подключения. 
Порт открыт, все в норме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Это не ответ`

Схема у вас такая:

```
               +--------+     +-------------+     +---------+
               |        |     |             |     |         |
Internet  +----> Router +-----> Raspberry Pi+----->    PC   |
               |        |     |             |     |         |
               +--------+     +-------------+     +---------+
              192.168.1.1      192.168.1.20      192.168.1.147
```

Правильно?

1. `Открыл порт 3389 для Raspberry` - где? На роутере? Для входящих (из интернета) подключений? И что значит *открыл*?
2. `нужно сделать включаемый/выключаемый проброс порта на PC` - что означает *включаемый/выключаемый*? Это какое-то событие, программный/механический триггер? Или это пока не принципиально?
3. `Т.е форвардинг.` Форвардинг и "проброс порта" - это разные вещи. Хотя на совсем бытовом уровне может показаться, что они (почти) одинаковы. В инфраструктуре iptables эти "действия" происходят в разных частях (таблицах, цепочках), и реально совершают различные действия над сетевым пакетом.
4. Чтобы решить ваш вопрос, надо однозначно понимать, что в итоге надо. Например, надо, чтобы пакет, пришедший из интернета на роутер на порт ХХХХ, прошел дальше на Raspberry Pi (на порт YYYY), а затем был передан на PC (на порт ZZZZ). В общем больше подробной информации.

**UPD**

Попробуйте такое правило:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.147:3389
```

eth0 - имя интерфейса может отличаться.

Но предварительно надо включить форвардинг: `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

**UPD 2**

Специальной команды у iptables типа disable/enable some_rule, на сколько я знаю, нет.

Но это можно реализовать несколькими способами.

Если это правило на RPI одно, то можно просто, например: `/etc/init.d/iptables start/stop`

Либо удалением/добавлением правила:

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.147:3389

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.147:3389
```

Comment: У меня запущен RDP терминал на PC. Открывать на прямую порт для глобальной сети - нет желания, т.к это не всегда безопасно. 
Т.е если мне нужен доступ к ПК по RDP - я отправляю команду RPI - та активирует режим переброса трафика через себя, тем самым делает PC доступным для подключения по RDP. Потом отключаю, и PC недоступен. 
1. Да, на роутере, т.е у RPI открыт порт для подключения из интернета. 
2. Это нужно обдумать, можно даже банально на Blynk управление сделать.(на выходе мне нужны 2 ssh команды, вкл/выкл переброс трафика).
3.Да, возможно я путаю. нужен переброс трафика.
4. Описал

Comment: PC и RPI подключены не последовательно, а параллельно между собой. Т.е роутер - узел, а PC  и RPI - две ветки исходящие из узла.

Comment: @PaTRoN_iX т.е. входящий на роутер трафик (на порт 3389) уже доходит до RPI? Получается осталось только научить RPI передавать трафик на PC? так?

Comment: Да. Верно. Именно в передаче трафика с RPI на PC у меня появились проблемы.

Comment: @PaTRoN_iX гляньте апдейт в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Еще вопрос. Как можно отключать это ?

Comment: @PaTRoN_iX см. UPD 2